Custom grub module
I would like to write custom grub module.
Followed below steps but this module is not getting compiled.
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/grub.git
cd grub; mkdir grub-core/my_module; vim grub-core/my_module/hello.c

Appended below into grub-core/Makefile.core.def
module = {
    name = hello;
    common = my_module/hello.c;
};

./autogen.sh; ./configure; make; make install

hello.c contains below code:
#include <grub/misc.h>

GRUB_MOD_INIT(hello) {
    grub_printf("Hello from custom GRUB module!\n"); }

GRUB_MOD_FINI(hello) {
    grub_printf("Goodbye from custom GRUB module!\n"); }


Programming questions belong on our sister site, Stack Overflow.
